# Why does Flow let you cast an Any type to, say, a Number in this example?

Tags: flowtype

In the [Flow docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/any/) about `Any` type, they say that it is not safe to use `Any` type and that if you do you should cast results of operations with that type as soon as possible to avoid `Any` leaking to other variables in your code. This casting is done in the line `let foo: number = obj.foo` below.

```
// @flow
function fn(obj: any) /* (:number) */ {
  let foo: number = obj.foo;
  let bar /* (:number) */ = foo * 2;
  return bar;
}

let bar /* (:number) */ = fn({ foo: 2 });
let baz /* (:string) */ = "baz:" + bar;
```

The argument to `fn`, for parameter `obj` can be anything. It's properties can have anything. **Why does flow let you even do the above-mentioned casting?** You cannot guarantee that foo will be a number since `obj.foo` can be anything.

Comment: `obj` is untyped. So flow has to be confident that your explicit type annotation `let foo: number` is correct. What would you expect from flow? To not trust your type annotation? If you want type safety, don't use `any`.

Comment: Yeah by using `any` you're literally telling it to do what you're frustrated that it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the *entire point* of `any` is to allow "any" operation to be performed on it.

This is basically like asking why your phone doesn't audibly ring when it's in silent mode. *That's the point of silent mode*. Change the ringer volume to something else (i.e. use `mixed`) if you'd like it to make noise.